# Time complexity to insert k elements into a binary heap which contains n elements

Tags: data-structures, binary-heap

What is the time complexity to insert k new elements into the binary heap which contains already n elements? I have constraint that I need to insert k elements in 0(k + Log n) complexity.

Hint: use a bottom-up approach similar to that for heap construction.

Comment: To insert 1 element you need log n time. So to insert k elements it would be O(k log n).

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy answer to this question.

A binary heap insertion will have average complexity of `O(1)` and worst-case of `O(log N)`. The complexity will remain within that bound regardless of `k`, but the actual time taken to complete the operation (not time complexity; I believe you might be confusing the terms) will depend on the implementation, platform, and the way the wind is blowing.

The closes thing to a concrete answer in terms of time is that the time taken to insert `k` elements at best be linearly *proportional* to `k` and at worst proportional to `log (x)` integrated from `N` to `k+N`. For `N` significantly larger than `k` we can approximate the time taken to *proportional* to `k log N`.

For more info see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap

Comment: So why the answer is more complicated than just: O(k) for average and O(k log(n)) for worst-case?

Comment: Because `k log (N)` is proportional to the time taken for the first insertion multiplied by `k`, it's a good approximation for k << N, which the OP does not specify. The actual amount will be proportional to `log N` for the first insertion, `log (N+1)` for the second, and so until we get to `log (N+k)`. The total time taken is therefore the integral over that range multiplied by `k`.

Comment: OK, so we have O(k log(n + k))

Comment: @AndyT that's worse than the worst case...

Comment: How do you get that the *average* complexity of insertion is `O(1)`? Seems like that's the *best case* time. Worst case is indeed `O(log n)`.

Comment: @JimMischel see the link at the bottom of the post.

Comment: You know, I've looked at that page many times and never noticed the discussion of the average complexity. I just "knew" that insert in a binary heap is O(log n). Thanks for making me read that.